# how to get the path of a route inside middleware in Koa

Tags: node.js, koa

How to get the actual path of the route without params.

Getting `/users/abc` expecting `/users/:id`

Route

```
router.get('/user/:id', find);
```

Middleware

```
const middleware= (ctx, next) => {
    let path = ctx.path; // '/users/abc'
   // Something 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const middleware= (ctx, next) => {
    let path = ctx._matchedRoute; // '/users/:id'
   // Something 
};
```

Source code

https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router/blob/master/lib/router.js#L336

https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router/blob/master/lib/layer.js#L46